# In VBA, looking to write a script that will carry out a function if a cell contains certain text, with ranges set as columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a long string of data with lots of columns. The columns all have names like "Person_1_Date", "Person_1_Name," "Person_2_Name," Person_2_Date" etc.

I'm trying to write a script that will take the titles for each person (Person_1, Person_2), etc. and re-arrange them in a particular order (Date, Name, Date, Name, rather than Date, Name, Name, Date, as it is here).

The rough partial script I'm experimenting with looks like the following so far:

```
Sub Test()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim k As Long
Set Rng = Columns("B:B")
    For k = Columns("B").Column To Columns("DE").Column Step 1
        If (IsNumber(Search("Person_x_Date", "k" & 1)) Then 'Looking to make this get called if the Search comes back with a number'
        Columns("k:k").Cut
        Rng.Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight 
    Next k
    End Sub
```

A few things I'm looking for help with. Is it possible to write a Search function that will look for parts of what's in a cell, while ignoring another? With `Person_x_Date` I'm hoping it to find a cell with anything in place of the x, so it could find Person_1_Date, Person_2_Date, etc. Is this possible?

The rest is a bit of a mess. Essentially, I want to set a range as a whole column, and if the search finds something, it'll copy and paste it into the correct place, and continue again until it finds what should come next (Like Person_X_Date).

I know the latter part of the code I wrote is quite far from that. I'm just looking for any kind of suggestions to help me put this together.

Comment: Is it always the case that a cell has a person's name, followed by an underscore, then some number, then another underscore, then a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that excel sorting can be done horizontally (most people just use it vertically).

This in effect allows you to sort columns into order based on values in a row.  (Normal vertical sorting will sort rows based on a value in a column).

In the sort dialogue, click the options button to choose horizontal sorting.

I think this will actually give you what you need.

however, if you need to manipulate the data values, you could create a formula row that changes the values and then sort on the data in the formula row..

Comment: NOTE: I think that using VBA to do the horizonal sort, will probably be the first thing you need to do, then you can modify the order of columns if needs be.  It depends on your data values,

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of this before. Thanks a million!

Comment: PS. If you need to manipulate the data value create a formula row the changes the values and then sort on the data in the formula row..

Comment: That's also a great suggestion. Is it possible to have a formula row that changes data values, even if they're words? Right now, I'm using Find/Replace to substitute words that'll make alphabetical order the same as the order I want (All Person_x_Name to be changed to Person_x_aName, for example, so they'll all appear before Person_x_Date when I arrange).